# jQuery show total li item using loop

Tags: jquery

Basically i wanna show total list items for each list item that contains sub ul, see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/NykJe/

```
<ul>
    <li>linkA</li>
    <li>linkB<span class="total"></span>
        <ul>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>linkC</li>
    <li>linkD<span class="total"></span>
        <ul>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

var total = $('ul li ul li').size();
$('.total').append('<div>'+ total +'</div>');
```

i wanna use loop that count each specific sub ul li items count and result will be LinkB 3 and LinkD 5 currently it shows LinkB 8, LinkD 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('ul li ul').each(function(){
  $(this).prev('.total').append('<div>'+ $(this).find('li').length +'</div>');
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NykJe/10/)**

Comment: thx, how can i select .total if it looks like this? <li><a href="#">linkD<span class="total"></span></a>

Comment: @questionMonster: `$(this).prev('a').find('.total')`

Comment: Man I love this solution. Thanks Sarfraz. I was using for loops in a separate function; learned something today.

Comment: :-) Does this mean you can chain descendant selectors in one jquery? I.e. is $('div#first a#second li ul span') a valid selector?

Comment: @JasperMogg: Technically it's valid selector but depends on what you mean by it. You might want to ask a question here on SO to know more about it :)

Comment: that would select the span which was a descendant of a ul, which was a descendant of an li, which was the descendant of an a of id 'second', which was a descendant of a div with id 'first', right?

Comment: @JasperMogg: Yep that's true. Basically jQuery has selectors like CSS which is why it is popular and easily adopted :) Same selector is also valid in CSS for example to style something in that hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. It simply writes out the count directly in the `span` tag, rather than adding a new element (no real need for an extra tag if all you want is to insert the number).

```
$('.total').each(function()
{
    $(this).html($(this).parent().find('li').length);                    
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kfmCX/).